# exercise with Conditional probability of dependent events

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

problem:After masks are produced by the factory, they appear in a test center, where they are tested for defects. Historically, only 10% of masks get a positive test result (meaning they are defective).

Let $T_1$= number of masks tested until first positive result, $T_2$= number of masks tested until second positive result.

Find $P(T_2=r\,∣\,T_1=n)$ and then, using it, $P(T_2=r)$.

I know $P(T_2=r\,∣\,T_1=n)=0.9^{r-1}\times 0.1$ , but don't know how to find $P(T_2=r)$.

Comment: Hint: $T_2=r$ means that the $r^{th}$ mask was defective  and that exactly one of the first $r-1$ masks was also defective.

Comment: Should it be $P(T_2=r | T_1= n) = 0.9^{\color{blue}{(r-n-1)}} \times 0.1$? You can use Bayes' rule : $P(T_2 = r) = \sum_{n=0}^{r-1} P(T_2 = r |T_1 = n) P(T_1 = n)$.

Comment: You have asked this question, or minor variants of it, three times now.  Why not take a look at the suggestions you have received and try to work on it yourself?